# Neyman-Pearson test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, neyman-pearson-lemma

Suppose $X$ is a random variable and two hypothesis defined as:

$$H_0:f(x;\lambda_{0}) = ‎\lambda_0 \exp(−\lambda_0 x)$$ 
$$H_1:f(x;\lambda_{1}) $$ 
$$x \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_1>\lambda_0$$

My question is that how we can make a Neyman-Pearson test for that?

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have $x_{1}...x_{n}\underset{iid}{\sim}exp\left(\lambda\right)$ samples where $\lambda$ is unknown.
We want to test the simple hypothesis $H_{0}:\,\,\lambda=\lambda_{0}$ versus the simple alternative $H_{1}:\,\,\lambda=\lambda_{1}$ then by Neyman–Pearson lemma we assured that the test $\mathbb{P}\left(T\left(x\right)>c\,|\,\lambda_{0}\right)=\alpha$ is the most powerful test where $T\left(x\right)=\frac{L\left(x,\lambda_{1}\right)}{L\left(x,\lambda_{0}\right)}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{1}e^{-\lambda_{1}x_{i}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{0}e^{-\lambda_{0}x_{i}}}$.

From now on it's just algebra (you'll need to use log at one point), but at the end you want a function of $x_i$ at one side of the inequality and a constant at the other side. You'll get eventually $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}<c^{'''}$, meaning your test statistic has the distrbution of $Gamma\left(n,\lambda\right)$.

Comment: For receiver operating characteristic, it gets to:$$P_d = \int_{0}^{K} {f_T(t|H_1)}dt$$ where $f_T(t|H_1)$ has the Gamma distribution; is that correct? And what is the final answer for the ROC? Here, $K$ is the value for RHS of the above equation after some simplification: $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}{x_i} < K$. It seems it is equal to the CDF of the Gamma function!?